# WHMCS intellisearch from shell

Tags: bash, shell, whmcs

WHMCS does not offer full search via API so I was wondering if there is a way to it in other ways via shell (yes, it needs to be bash).

The goal is to perform a full search (clients, products,orders, tickets, domains etc ...).

For example, I might have a client that registered an account under a certain domain that was registered elsewhere. Using the GetDomains/GetClients/GetOrders is will not yield results. Yet, the account's main domain is linked to the account.

Performing a full search checks it all and the results can be filtered and that is what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should edit your question to include some more details of what you're trying to do.  "Full search" of what?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heared of search via API in WHMCS unfortunately. Would like that as well.

But you should be able to create something with CURL and hit the search.php which is used in admin search interface.

parameters:

value=[Your search string]

intellisearch=1

token=[You have to curl a page first and parse the html to get this]

Make sure to first login against WHMCS with your script.

This is not the most beautiful solution, but the easiest if you don't want to access database directly.